# GraphQL Query Nested Object

Tags: graphql, strapi

I'm new to GraphQL, reading up on the documentation and just messing around so apologies in advance for any lack of understanding here (including whether or not this is impossible). My schema is generated by the CMS I'm using (Strapi).

I am wondering if it is possible to query a field on a nested component?

For example, say there is a `Restaurant` object

```
{
    "name": "Luigi's Pizza",
    "michelinStars": 1
    "page": {
      "title": "Luigi's Pizza | The Best Pizza in Italy",
      "slug": "luigis-pizza"
    }
}
```

I can query for a `Restaurant` with `Restaurants(where: {michelinStars: 1})` etc, but if I wanted to get the `Restaurant` with the `slug` "luigis-pizza", I'm struggling to work out how. Pseduo code for what I want to do:

```
query {
    Restaurants(where: { page: { slug: "luigis-pizza" } }) {
        name
    }
}
```

Is this possible? And if so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: It's not really clear from the Strapi docs if this is possible yet. I thought it was on their roadmap, implemented and then rolled back. You can access the GraphQL Playground interface for your endpoint as long as you're not running in production. Using the autocomplete function or the "Docs" link, you can see whether the `where` argument takes anything like `certification`.

Comment: @DanielRearden thanks for the response! I think you are right, at least it's not possible yet.

Comment: @DanielRearden Do you have any recommendations or work arounds for this? All I can think of is creating a separate content type for certification and creating a relation. The issue is that makes things a lot more complicated when it comes to creating/editing fields as you can't create and edit another content type within the view of another like you can with components

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with last version of Strapi and the deep filter is working well.

Here is a short video of what I did - https://www.loom.com/share/cf8360252b1044128c9b07a2bb390638

Comment: Just want to start off by saying, I love Strapi!! It's an amazing platform, and it will save me so much time, so thank you to you and the team for all the work you've put in!!
One difference is that the Certification is a component, as I need to customize the fields within the Teacher view.
The use case is actually as a "Page" component. It will hold things like meta description, slug, etc (which will always vary). It will be assigned to more than one Content Type. Although the "Page" would work as its own Content Type, it will make things more tricky for editors as it can't be edited in...

Comment: ...the view. When it comes to non-developers editing the Content Types, there are probably going to be issues (as we are using Strapi as a CMS) as it's not as easy to jump from Content Type to Content Type as it is to edit a component within the view of the Content Type you're already in.
I've updated my question with a more appropriate example, maybe that will help explain. This misunderstanding is my bad as I didn't mention component anywhere!!

Comment: Ho okay! It's related to this issue then - https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5124

Comment: The video is no longer available (404) and it would be helpful if you'd write some text in your answer to describe what your solution is.